# How to run PHP or ruby scripts using g-wan?

Tags: php, ruby, g-wan

I have php5-cli and ruby installed but both don't work !

In the log I have
* bug in new /home/olivier/gwan/0.0.0.0_8080/#0.0.0.0/csp/php.php

Where php.php is a simple :

```
<?php
  echo "Hello World";
?>
```

In gwan.log, I don't see anything about loading my php script !?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The currently available G-WAN v3.3.28 doesn't support PHP. G-WAN v3.10 (which is said to be released this month) will have PHP support according to the author: http://gwan.ch/blog/20121021.html

Comment: Thank you ... It looks promising !

Comment: Note that the same goes for Ruby (and Perl, Python, Go...) which has been implemented very recently in the development release.

Comment: Any roadmap for the release ? A beta version available ? An alpha version available ?

Comment: Yes, for registered 'Enterprise' users. Note that many benchmarks give a 'feel' of the new version: http://gwan.com/imgs/gwan_hello.c.png
http://gwan.com/imgs/gwan_hello.cs.png
http://gwan.com/imgs/gwan_hello.java.png
http://gwan.com/imgs/gwan_hello.js.png
http://gwan.com/imgs/gwan_hello.lua.png
http://gwan.com/imgs/gwan_hello.php.png
http://gwan.com/imgs/gwan_hello.pl.png
http://gwan.com/imgs/gwan_hello.py.png
http://gwan.com/imgs/gwan_hello.rb.png
http://gwan.com/imgs/gwan_hello.scala.png Now that G-WAN supports 15 languages, there are many opportunities for developers of all horizons.

Comment: So, no public info about the next release date ? And what is the twitter account of g-wan ? Thanks Gil !